# Посоветуйте годное руководство для новичков по написанию чат-бота в telegram

Tags: java

Начну с небольшого предисловия. Когда-то давно изучал python по книге, затем пробовал смотреть курсы, но понял что такими методами не получается лично для меня учится. Нужна практика на конкретном примере. Поработав немного в digital научился собирать чат-ботов в telegram, но на конструкторах, посему хочу написать свой чат бот и ощутить процесс написания кода.

Нашел в интернете статью по написанию бота на java (захотел попробовать java) код следующий:

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
                <artifactId>telegram</retifactId>
                <version>3.5<version>
</dependency>

public class Bot extends telegramLongPollingBot {
/** 
*метод для приема сообщений.
*@param update содержит сообщение от пользователя.
 */
 @Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
String message = update.getMassage().getText();
sendMsg(update.getMassage().getChatId().toString(), message);
}

/**
Метод для настройки сообщения и его оправки.
*@param chatId id чата
*param s Стпока, которую необходимо отправить в качестве сообщения.
 */
 public synchronized void sendMsg(String chatId, String s) {
    SendMessage sendMassege = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
    sendMassege.setChatId(chatId);
    sendMassege.setText(s);
    try {
        sendMassege(sendMassege);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception: ", e.toString());
    }
}
/**
*Метод возвращает имя бота, указанное при регистрации.
"@return имя бота
" */
@Override
public String getBotUsername(Eajs_bot) {
    return "BotName";
    }

/**
*Метод возвращает token бота для связи с сервером Telegram
*@return token для бота
 */
 @Override
 public String getBotToken(6011391381:AAFQ1lrRFgp-2uOCwfLmOX8vnsMKob4S9vk) {
    return "BotToken";
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApiContestInitializer.init();
    TelegramBotsAPI telegramBotsApi = TelegramBotsApi();
    try {
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(Bot.getBot());
    } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```

При запуске кода пишет, что все готово, но ничего не происходит. Хочется собрать конкретный небольшой чат-бот, может подскажите как на примере текущего кода научиться его читать или собрать по какому-то свежему примеру сборки чат-бота.

Заранее прошу прощения в it я еще даже не новичок, поэтому какие-то вещи наверное будут глупые в вопросе, но очень хочется попробовать разобраться и создать маленький чат-бот, который буду понимать как работает.

Ссылки на ресурсы и для чего они приветствуются.

Comment: Пойти по пути умного совета который вы отбросили в прошлом и почитать таки книги по предполагаемому ЯП.

Comment: боюсь, что джава - не конструктор чат - ботов, тут вот так с наскока по примеру на коленке не выйдет. хотя сама идея учиться на реальном проекте хорошая. просто без азов в дажеве это примерно тоже самое, что с утра выйти на даче в огород и попытаться строить шатл.

Comment: Хотел как раз не просто книжку читать, а сразу на проекте пробовать. У примеру начал изучать классы и сразу применил их на реальном проекте и посмотрел как это работает. Делаешь проект и параллельно читаешь документацию. 

Только стартануть бы с тех материалов, где можно повторить код и понять что сделал, а дальше знания применять на этом же проекте.